# How to have mutliple webhosts on a single internal network?

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, domain, minecraft

Here is my current setup. A Raspberry Pi hosting a webserver on my domain(lets say mydomain.com) on ports 443 and 80. I am also hosting a Minecraft server, but I can only connect to it on my local network as I have not port forwarded yet as I am trying to create a way for me to make my Minecraft server on an old PC in that same internal network be accessible through mc.mydomain.com. How can I do that?

As a bonus to add complications, I am also trying to host a NGINX management panel on the old PC for the Minecraft server on panel.mydomain.com :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The ninecraft server will use different ports to http(s), so simply port forward those lirts to the appropriate server.  For running 2 http(s) servers off 1 IP you could combine them onto 1 IP and use name based virtual hosting and then use a reverse proxy. Both nginx and Apache can act as reverse proxies.

Comment: Search this site for previous threads about "reverse proxy".

Comment: @davidgo, any resources that I should reference too to help the process?

Comment: Your question lacks enough specificity to help.  The webserver the Pi is running, if you have forwarded port 80 and 443 on the server would be a good start.  Depending on the specifity others may be able to help you better if you include the make and model of your router and the IP addresses of the various devices

Comment: @davidgo it’s a Linksys router, I have a website connected to my raspberry pi, connected over 80 and 443. Then I have a server panel that’s open on a 2015 mac book air running Ubuntu 21.1 on the same local network. I want to connect that server through panel.mydomain.com. Then I will also have mc.mydomain.com to connect to the mc server on that same host.

Comment: Im not personally interested in providing a step by step response, but even if I wanted to I could not do it without knowing the web servers deployed.  One thing that may be useful to you - Name based virtual hosting and SNI (Apache and Nginx both support these) allow 1 IP with multiple domains.  So at least from that pov, you pount all the subdomains at the web server and have it reverse proxy to other local servers or respond directly as appropriate.

Comment: @davidgo I wasn’t asking for step by step. What you provided was adequate. Thank you for your help